# consistent display of panel body bootstrap

Tags: java, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to list all the files on my device on the browser , I've managed to give each file a proper html5 tag for example

```
path = "/Files/f/extensions/folder.png";
        if (f.listFiles() != null)// cant access some files (security issues
                                    // like d:/reposotories)..
            tag = "<div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-4 \" >" + "<div class=\"panel panel-default\" >" + "<div class=\"panel-heading\" > <h2>"
                    + "@name@ </h2>" + "</div>" + "<div class=\"panel-body\" >"
                    + "<a href=\"@href@\"><img src=\"@path@\"  class=\" img img-responsive\"  /></a>"
                    + "</div><div class=\"panel-footer\" > " + "<ul>" + " <li> " + f.listFiles().length + " Files</li> "
                    + " <li> last modified : @lastModified@</li> " + "</ul>"  + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>";
```

I use to display directories. and

```
(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("gif") || extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") || extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")
                || extension.equalsIgnoreCase("png")) {
            tag = "<div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-4 \" >" + "<div class=\"panel panel-default\" >" + "<div class=\"panel-heading\" > <h2>"
                    + "@name@ </h2>" + "</div>" + "<div class=\"panel-body\" >"
                    + "<a href=\"@href@\"><img src=\"@path@\"  class=\" img img-responsive\" /></a>"
                    + "</div><div class=\"panel-footer\" > " + "<ul>" + " <li> size : @fileSize@</li> " + " <li> last modified : @lastModified@</li> "
                    + "</ul>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>";
```

to display images where all @xxx@ is a placeholder that will be replaced as needed, however there is a problem that the body of the panel takes different dimensions and that's ruining the display of the page , [image]

and since the second panel adjusted itself automatically to match the image that column in the second row couldn't be used

Comment: Is the issue that the two end images are stacked?

Comment: yes and no the problem is that I want a fixed size for all the panel bodies no matter what content they hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a custom class e.g fixed-300 that fixes the width. See below the css styles.

```
tag = "<div class=\"col-sm-6 col-md-4 fixed-300\" >" 
+ "<div class=\"panel panel-default\" >" 
+ "<div class=\"panel-heading text-center\" >"
+ "<h2>@name@</h2>" 
+ "</div>" 
+ "<div class=\"panel-body\" >"
+ "<a href=\"@href@\"><img src=\"@path@\"  class=\" img img-responsive\" /></a>"
+ "</div>"
+ "<div class=\"panel-footer\" > " 
+ "<ul>" 
+ "<li> size : @fileSize@</li> " 
+ "<li> last modified : @lastModified@</li> "
+ "</ul>" 
+ "</div>" 
+ "</div>" 
+ "</div>";
```

You also have to englobe all tags in a div:

```
<div class="row equal">....</div>
```

CSS styles:

```
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 1 auto;
}
.fixed-300 {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/713qyn1w/) to see how it looks like.

If you need more detailed explication, please give me a sign. I'll be very pleased to help.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: it didn't work as you expected I changed the display to table , gave a better result but with spaces : [look](http://jsfiddle.net/hmdv3125/1/) how your code behaves

Comment: That's because you have changed the style of the 8th panel. Please, see the comment [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/hmdv3125/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the dynamic height of the elements. If you give each element a class with a specific height, it should fix the problem. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9593/) (responsive, so pull container).

I've given each of the items a class, which contains a height of 50px:

```
.sameHeight{
   height: 50px;
}
```

and bootstrap handles the width just fine.